# How to implement a clean base test class with common Assert methods (F#)

Tags: f#

I'm trying to createa a base test class where I can setup common methods.

```
type BaseTest() =

    member self.Assert (functionToEvaluate:bool, ?errorMessage:string) =    
        let a = fun () -> defaultArg errorMessage ""    
        match errorMessage with
        | None -> NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(functionToEvaluate)
        | _ -> NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(functionToEvaluate, a )

[<TestFixture>]
type MyTest () =
    inherit BaseTest()

    [<Test>]
    member self.``test something``() =
        let x = 1
        self.Assert_( (x = 2))
        // or 
        self.Assert_( (x = 2), "x value is not 2")
```

1. How to make the code "clean" (`let a ...` is horrible for me)
2. How to avoid using *this/self* in the derived class?
3. How can I write it like `self.Assert(x=1)` or even better just `Assert(x=1)` instead of `self.Assert((x=1))` ?

What I want tot do (and I can do with C#) is this:

```
// in base test class
protected void Assert(bool test) => NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(test);
protected void Assert(bool test, string errorMessage) => NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(test, errorMessage);

// in test class
public void TestSomething() {
     var x = 1
     Assert(x==2)
     // or
     Assert(x==2, "x is not 2")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to translate the C# program into F# verbatim and expect it to look "nice" without realizing that the initial C# program is already full of C#-specific tricks that exist in order to make it look "nice". One example is the base class. Why is there a base class? Does it represent something? No, it doesn't: it's there for the sole purpose of avoiding a class name when calling these functions - i.e. you write `Assert` instead of `SomeHelper.Assert`. This stems out of the fact that in C# you can't have free-standing functions.

But in F# - you can!

```
let assrt x = NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(x)
let assrtWith x msg = NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(x, msg)

[<TestFixture>]
type SaleRepositoryTest () =

    [<Test>]
    member self.``test something``() =
        let x = 1
        assrt (x=2)
        assrtWith (x=2) "x is not 2"
```

(Note that you can't use the name `assert`, because it's a keyword)

Also note that you generally **don't need classes**. The fact that in C# you can't do anything without them is a giant mistake that grows out of Java design, which was a misunderstanding of OO.

You can have free-standing functions. If I remember correctly, NUnit should be able to discover such tests just fine (though I can't verify right now):

```
let [<Test>] ``test something``() =
    let x = 1
    assrt (x=2)
    assrtWith (x=2) "x is not 2"
```

Finally, I strongly recommend that you consider [`FsUnit`](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/). It can bind to NUnit (if you're locked into that) and provides a nice library of F#-idiomatic assertions.

Comment: FsUnit, great tip, thanks.  I didn't used a class initially but trying to have an overload of my _Assert_  I finished to use an optional argument (that is only allowed in a type member). Now I know that is not the way... thanks

Comment: +1. Also, when using FsUnit, open the FsUnitTyped namespace (rather than the FsUnit namespace)  because the typesafe assertions are nicer to work with.